# Responsive font size based on size of container

Tags: jquery, css, font-size

In a nutshell I'm trying to make these symbols "90%" (for instance) of the size of the container div. Also, the font-size has to be responsive on `window.resize`.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/b7g1bxqw/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Viewport Percentage Units could help you here.

Try somthing like this:

```css
.chessGrid1, .chessGrid2 {
 width:11.11%;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
    font-size: 10vw;
}
```

See also an older post for more information: [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Hope it helps...

Comment: Tried that, but it applies to the viewport rather than the .chessGrid container so it overlaps the boxes

Comment: And I can't use @media queries because the page is totally responsive and as such I can't specify a max-width unless I do it for every pixel

Comment: Am getting so near:

$(document).ready(function() {
    var fontSize = parseInt($(".chessGrid").width())+"px";
    $(".chessGrid").css('font-size', fontSize);
 }); 

But how can I make it do it on window.resize?!